# How to use TfidfVectorizer for multiple txt files to get one data frame in python

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

I have to convert multiple text files (.txt) from a directory into one data frame using TfidfVectorizer.

I need to export the data frame to a directory. I have to write python code.

**code**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

files = [file for file in os.listdir('E:/train/r/') if file.endswith('.txt')] 
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf = True) 
tfidf_vectorizer_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(files) 
df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vectorizer_vectors.T.todense(),
                  index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 
                  columns=["tfidf"]) df.sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False)
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide us some code that you've been worked on it, and where you get trouble.

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer()
files = [file for file in os.listdir('E:\train\r\') if file.endswith('.txt')]
tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True) 
tfidf_vectorizer_vectors=tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(files)
df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vectorizer_vectors.T.todense(), index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["tfidf"]) df.sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False)

I don't know I wrote this code in right way.

Comment: you can use `ctrl+k'